# Is there any data that would indicate a correlation between stellar metallicity and the actual metal content of bodies in orbit?

Tags: science-based, space-colonization, interstellar-travel

Metallicity measures the heavy element load of a star, heavy being defined as "not Hydrogen or Helium", but doesn't give a direct indication as to how much of a star is what might be called "industrially significant elements", and that material is not exactly easily accessible. Is there any data we can use to make an estimate as to the bulk elemental make up of material in a exoplanetary system based on the composition of the star it orbits?

I'm picking that if we start colonising space it will be from a position of at least fledgling space based industrial processing. That means that the accessibility of materials like Titanium, Tungsten, Gold, Rhenium, and Niobium will be an important point in assessing the prospects in a given star system ahead of time.

Comment: [It amazes me how many elements can be distinguished from the emission spectrum of a distant star!]  (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03611-2.epdf?sharing_token=74ZOiP_Tkbs3MMVPT5oMy9RgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0NGmkdPeW2TMrOeH3MpePAmVIpSjNQ7aDUff8if2O3GSdbVxXTvA1SwxFekkfcD9XfP6xsRSSiUl6fXxeV-zB7op6kCSk94IOSj5EhGWQd1Ymaq8GhLYEtHsa1coQ1_r5TLnUmf2kRC8AVLKQtbeVGmlJG-m86pYWgqf3StAV_KkzMyW9P2i4r7Puhh0B7_ndk%3D&tracking_referrer=www.sciencenews.org) All of them are glowy plasma I am sure.  I see emission spectra for exoplanet atmospheres.  But how to detect cold elements in the crust?

Comment: @Willk I'm not sure if they can yet, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's a single data point, we can look at our [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun#Composition) and its planets.

> The Sun is composed primarily of the chemical elements hydrogen and helium. At this time in the Sun's life, they account for 74.9% and 23.8% of the mass of the Sun in the photosphere, respectively. All heavier elements, called metals in astronomy, account for less than 2% of the mass, with oxygen (roughly 1% of the Sun's mass), carbon (0.3%), neon (0.2%), and iron (0.2%) being the most abundant.
>
> The Sun's original chemical composition was inherited from the interstellar medium out of which it formed. Originally it would have contained about 71.1% hydrogen, 27.4% helium, and 1.5% heavier elements.
>
> Since the Sun formed, the main fusion process has involved fusing hydrogen into helium. Over the past 4.6 billion years, the amount of helium and its location within the Sun has gradually changed. Within the core, the proportion of helium has increased from about 24% to about 60% due to fusion, and some of the helium and heavy elements have settled from the photosphere towards the center of the Sun because of gravity. The proportions of metals (heavier elements) is unchanged.

If we compare those numbers with what we have on [Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth#Chemical_composition) we see that the relative abundances are completely skewed with respect to the Sun

> Earth's mass [...] is composed mostly of iron (32.1%), oxygen (30.1%), silicon (15.1%), magnesium (13.9%), sulfur (2.9%), nickel (1.8%), calcium (1.5%), and aluminum (1.4%), with the remaining 1.2% consisting of trace amounts of other elements. Due to mass segregation, the core region is estimated to be primarily composed of iron (88.8%), with smaller amounts of nickel (5.8%), sulfur (4.5%), and less than 1% trace elements.

What about [Jupiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter#Composition)?

> Jupiter's upper atmosphere is about 90% hydrogen and 10% helium by volume. Since helium atoms are more massive than hydrogen molecules, Jupiter's atmosphere is approximately 75% hydrogen and 24% helium by mass, with the remaining one percent consisting of other elements. [...] The interior of Jupiter contains denser materials—by mass it is roughly 71% hydrogen, 24% helium, and 5% other elements.

I think the furthest we can go is simply in assessing that, the latest the generation a star belongs to, the more elements its planets can have. But where can they be possibly located can be hardly inferred by the star composition alone.

Comment: Yeah I already figured that the younger generations of stars, that formed when there were more elements in the universe at large, were going to be the prize targets, all else being equal (a Flare Star is a bad neighbourhood even if their attendant worlds are gold plated). People keep telling me we'll be careful and considered in stellar colonisation (I doubt it) so I was wondering if we had any data to do that with in this particular regard yet.